# org.openapitools.codegen.SpecValidationException when using openapi-generator-maven-plugin for openapi version 3.1.0

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I'm getting [ERROR] Error resolving ./paths/daas/res_prod_acptd_art_cnts.yaml
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 2, org.openapitools.codegen.SpecValidationException -Illegal character in opaque part at index 2 for the following yaml

```
openapi: 3.1.0
info:
  title: test
  description: test
  # TODO: termsOfService field should be added later
  contact:
    name: test Support
    email: test
  version: 0.0.1
  license: 
    name: Copyright 
    identifier: EPL-2.0

servers:
- url: http://localhost:8080/api
  description: Localhost for development purposes
  
# TODO: Add the security requirments object later
security: []
tags:
  - name: DaaS RES Production Service
    description: Research workflow Production stage related DaaS Production Service APIs
  
paths:
  # Production Service
  /{tenantId}/counts:
    $ref: 'paths/daas/res_prod_acptd_art_cnts.yaml'
```

$ref: 'paths/daas/res_prod_acptd_art_cnts.yaml'

```
post:
  summary: Production Accepted Article Counts
  description: API to request counts of production accepted articles by article classification type and other specified global filtering criteria.
  tags:
    - DaaS RES Production Service
  operationId: postProductionAcceptedArticleCounts
  requestBody:
    description: Contains the parameter combination that must be applied to generate the response
    content:
      'application/json':
        schema:
          $ref: '../../components/daas/requestBodies/ReqPayloadProdAcptdArtCnts.yaml'
        examples:
          example-1:
            value:
              $ref: '../../components/daas/examples/ReqExProdAcptdArtCnts.yaml'
          example-2:
            value:
              $ref: '../../components/daas/examples/ReqEx2ProdAcptdArtCnts.yaml'
          example-3:
            value:
              $ref: '../../components/daas/examples/ReqEx3ProdAcptdArtCnts.yaml'
          example-4:
            value:
              $ref: '../../components/daas/examples/ReqEx4ProdAcptdArtCnts.yaml'    
    required: true
  responses:
    '200':
      $ref: '../../components/daas/responses/ResPayloadProdAcptdArtCnts.yaml'
    '400':
      $ref: '../../components/daas/responses/400BadRequest.yaml'
    '401':
      $ref: '../../components/daas/responses/401Unauthorized.yaml'
    '415':
      $ref: '../../components/daas/responses/415UnsupportedMediaType.yaml'
    '500':
      $ref: '../../components/daas/responses/500InternalServerError.yaml'
parameters:
- name: tenantId
  in: path
  description: Tenant ID of the tenant of which the caller is invoking the API of.
  required: true
  schema:
    type: string
  example: '1001'
```

Comment: It's probably because OpenAPI Generator [does not support OpenAPI 3.1 yet](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/9083). If you change `openapi: 3.1.0` to `openapi: 3.0.0`, does the error go away?

Comment: I'm using openapi-generator-maven-plugin 6.3.0 and it gives some errors like symbol:   class GenericType
  location: class org.openapitools.client.model.AbstractOpenApiSchema

Comment: Can you post the contents of the `paths/daas/res_prod_acptd_art_cnts.yaml` file?

Comment: I added to the description @Helen